# Pure render and button onClick inline setStates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When talking about pure render methods in React and how setting state inside of render is a serious anti-pattern, how strictly we are speaking about this? I get that if I do a setState inside a render function, which doesn't require any user input, it can create infinite loops and re-renders.

What I don't understand is, does this rule apply also when writing a page element that receives input from user? I mean, what's the difference between these two ways to write a simple click-handler for a button:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div className="container-fluid info-modal">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col col-12">
          <InfoModal active={this.state.modalActive}>
            <h2>Fine dining recipes</h2>
            <p>Here you can publish your fine dining recipes. Don't forget to 
            include every ingredient needed!</p>
            <Button
              title="ok"
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ modalActive: false })
              }}
            />
          </InfoModal>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

vs.

```
render() {
  return(
  <div className="container-fluid info-modal">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col col-12">
      <InfoModal active={this.state.modalActive}>
      <h2>Fine dining recipes</h2>
      <p>Here you can publish your fine dining recipes. Don't forget to 
      include every ingredient needed!</p>
      <Button
              title="ok"
              onClick={() => {
                this.closeModal()
              }}
      />
      </InfoModal>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  )
}
```

I get that for a more complicated components, probably the right way to do this would be to use a click-handler which this class receives as an property, but for simple use cases, are there really some concrete harm in setting the state inside an inline click-handler?

Comment: onclick shouldnt have quotes - it should be wrapped with `onClick={() => {}}`

Comment: honestly, both methods are accepted within React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When docs say that you must not `setState` within render it means that that the `setState` function must not be called as soon as we render and not that setState cannot be written inside render

so when you write

```
 <Button
      title="ok"
      onClick={() => {
         this.setState({ modalActive: false })
     }}
 />
```

You are not actually calling setState in render but you are calling it on `click` action of button which are 2 different things

So whether you write

```
 <Button
      title="ok"
      onClick={() => {
          this.closeModal()
      }}
  />
```

or

```
<Button
    title="ok"
    onClick={() => {
        this.setState({ modalActive: false })
    }}
 />
```

are equivalent if you just setState inside `closeModal`

A call that will not be accepted is below

```
<Button
      title="ok"
      onClick={this.setState({ modalActive: false })}
 />
```

Comment: Just to add to you answer. The same applies to hooks too. Should not call any hook in render. The last example you have actually points out two "bad" things. 1. The content of `onClick` is executed on render as it has the `()` meaning the whatever the function returns is actually assigned to `onClick`. 2. `setState` is the one being executed causing a render loop.